# How can I append this list?

Tags: python

this is my code on python 3.2.3 IDLE:

```
numbers = []
numbers = input("(Enter a empty string to quit) Enter a number: ")
while numbers != "":
    numbers = input("(Enter a empty string to quit) Enter a number; ")
numbers.append(n)
print ("The list is", numbers)
```

problem now is, i can't append the list. 
if i make numbers = int(input( then it works for appending the list but won't let me quit out of entering the numbers. 
if i make numbers = input
like i have right now, it won't let me append the list

how can i get these numbers to append to a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. you're assigning the input to `numbers` instead of `n`;
2. the `append()` is in the wrong place.

Try the following:

```
numbers = []
n = input("(Enter a empty string to quit) Enter a number: ")
while n != "":
    numbers.append(n)
    n = input("(Enter a empty string to quit) Enter a number; ")
print ("The list is", numbers)
```

If you want to store integers instead of string, change the `append()` line to:

```
    numbers.append(int(n))
```

Stylistically, if the first prompt is the same as the prompt for all subsequent inputs, I'd restructure the code as follows:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    n = input("(Enter a empty string to quit) Enter a number: ")
    if n == "": break
    numbers.append(n) # or int(n)
print ("The list is", numbers)
```

Comment: And that the `append` is outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: Plus, if you want to append numbers instead of strings, it should be `numbers.append (int (n))`.

Comment: Plus this will ignore the first input.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the problems you've got an answer to, this can be heavily simplified for simple data input:

```
numbers = list(map(int, iter(input, '')))
```

Working inside-out (a bit of explanation):

- `iter(input, '')` repeatedly calls until `''` (an empty input) is met and `yields` that   value
- the `map(int,...)` takes those values and tries to convert to an integer - an exception will be thrown if it can't
- the `list(...)` then takes that and creates an actual `list` object
- `numbers = ...` is err, as it says :)

Then, possibly wrap in a function (using `functools.partial` here, but lambda is fine):

```
def ask(prompt):
    from functools import partial
    prompt_func = partial(input, prompt)
    return list(map(int, iter(prompt_func, '')))

numbers = ask('Keep entering valid numbers (or a blank line to quit)')
```

Comment: Though without some explanation of what's going on here, it approaches voodoo code...

Comment: @sr2222 agreed - just seems more simple to me - tried to explain it for future reference though